# convert source code java language to C# language

Tags: java, c#

I find this source code on internet. this source code on java language, how to convert this source code to c# language. make it to instance object.

```
 public enum Prioritas 
 {
    SANGAT_RENDAH(1), RENDAH(2), SEDANG(3), TINGGI(4), SANGAT_TINGGI(5);

    private int value;

    private Prioritas(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue () 
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that: *Java enum* into *C#* one:

```
public enum Prioritas {
  SANGAT_RENDAH = 1, // Technically, assignments are not necessary here and below
  RENDAH = 2,
  SEDANG = 3,
  TINGGI = 4,
  SANGAT_TINGGI = 5,
}

public static class PrioritasExtensions {
  // technically you don't want it, since you can cast to int
  public static int getValue(this Prioritas value) {
    return (int) value;
  }
}
```

....

```
Prioritas priority = Prioritas.SEDANG;
// or just cast: 
// int value = (int) priority; 
int value = priority.getValue(); // 3
```

Comment: I've voted up, but IMO, `PrioritasExtensions` should be thrown away. Cast is a right way to go here. OP code shouldn't be translated 1-1.

Comment: I've added `PrioritasExtensions` just to show how to *add* methods for enums in C# (since Java allowes that)